# Python: Looking to display multiple figures in the same window

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having difficulty getting my four plots to show up in the same window without them a) overwriting or b) getting an error:

> [AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt']

Here is the section of code that I am trying to fix:

```
if(debug_on):      
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True, sharey=True)
    img_1 = remap.pedf(upsampled_smoothed_mag1)
    im_1 = axs[0,0].plt.imshow(img_1,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=[0,img_1.shape[1],0,img_1.shape[0]])                            
    fig.colorbar(im_1),
    plt.title('Unsampled smoothed - 1')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.05)

    img_2 = remap.pedf(upsampled_smoothed_mag2)
    im_2 = axs[0,1].plt.imshow(img_2,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=[0,img_2.shape[1],0,img_2.shape[0]])
    fig.colorbar(im_2)
    plt.title('Unsampled smoothed - 2')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.05)

    img_3 = remap.pedf(upsampled_smoothed_mag1_2)
    im_3 = axs[1,0].plt.imshow(img_3,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=[0,img_3.shape[1],0,img_3.shape[0]])                            
    fig.colorbar(im_3)
    plt.title('Unsampled smoothed - 1 (2.0)')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.05)

    img_4 = remap.pedf(upsampled_smoothed_mag2_2)
    im_4 = axs[1,1].plt.imshow(img_4,aspect='auto',origin='lower',extent=[0,img_4.shape[1],0,img_4.shape[0]])
    fig.colorbar(im_4)
    plt.title('Unsampled smoothed - 2 (2.0)')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(0.05)
```

Thanks in advance for the help! P.S. I am very much a novice!

Comment: If you're operating on an axis object rather than a plot or figure object, you need to use the `ax.` function rather than `plt.`

Comment: `axs[0,0].plt.imshow` is non-sensical. Either use `plt.imshow` or `axs[0,0].imshow`.